Exporting only dev dependencies
Is there a command for uv that exports/extracts just the dependencies declared as dev dependencies from the pyproject.toml file, for example to pass test dependencies to tox?
uv add Django
uv add pytest --dev

Results in this pyproject.toml:
[project]
dependencies = [
    "django>=4.2.15",
]

[tool.uv]
dev-dependencies = [
    "pytest>=8.3.2",
]

How can I generate a file that only contains the dev dependencies, basically a requirements-dev.txt?
uv pip compile pyproject.toml does not include the dev deps, only the main deps. And I did not see an argument to make it include it:
Resolved 4 packages in 83ms
# This file was autogenerated by uv via the following command:
#    uv pip compile pyproject.toml
asgiref==3.8.1
    # via django
django==4.2.15
    # via hatch-demo (pyproject.toml)
sqlparse==0.5.1
    # via django
typing-extensions==4.12.2
    # via asgiref

For comparison, poetry has poetry export --only dev -o requirements-dev.txt, which will generate something like this:
iniconfig==2.0.0 ; python_version >= "3.12" and python_version < "4.0"
packaging==24.1 ; python_version >= "3.12" and python_version < "4.0"
pluggy==1.5.0 ; python_version >= "3.12" and python_version < "4.0"
pytest==8.3.2 ; python_version >= "3.12" and python_version < "4.0"


See also: https://github.com/astral-sh/uv/issues/6429 and https://github.com/astral-sh/uv/issues/6007

Also, there is a PEP out that addresses dev dependencies: https://peps.python.org/pep-0735/ And the corresponding ticket on uv's github: https://github.com/astral-sh/uv/issues/5632

Update uv to the version 0.4.11 or greater (uv self update), and use the following command:
uv export --only-dev --no-hashes | awk '{print $1}' FS=' ;' > requirements-dev.txt

The uv tool doesnt provide a direct command to export only the dev dependencies into a requirements-dev.txt file similar to how Poetry does it. However, you can achieve this manually filtering the dev dependencies from the pyproject.toml file and creating a requirements-dev.txt file. To do it manually, you need to do this:

Open your pyproject.toml file and locate the [tool.uv.dev-dependencies] section.
Copy the list of dev dependencies
Create a new file named requirements-dev.txt.
Pase the dev dependencies into this file, ensuring that each dependency is on a new line.

Thankfully, you can automate this process with the following script:
import toml

# Load the pyproject.toml file
with open('pyproject.toml', 'r') as file:
    pyproject = toml.load(file)

# Extract the dev dependencies
dev_dependencies = pyproject.get('tool', {}).get('uv', {}).get('dev-dependencies', [])

# Write to requirements-dev.txt
with open('requirements-dev.txt', 'w') as file:
    for dep in dev_dependencies:
        file.write(dep + '\n')

This script will read the pyproject.toml, extract the dev dependencies and write them into your requirements-dev.txt file.

Thanks for the input, but if uv doesn't provide that feature then I'd rather declare the dev requirements as extras (which is something pip knows and understands), instead of adding yet another tool-specific script to the pipeline.

Thats fair, i dont think it makes too much of a difference either way. Just depends how you like it.

It seems uv has now introduced the feature (running 0.4.18 here):
Options:
[...]
      --only-dev                           Omit non-development dependencies

